# Play animation with the help of the animator once, wait until it ends playing and continue script code

Tags: unity, animation

How can I play animation with the help of the animator once, wait until it ends playing and continue script code?

I am playing an animation with the help of the animator this way:

```
animator.SetBool(what, toAnimate);
```

1. I am starting my animation in that way:

   rabit.animate("die", true);
2. I am making a transition to another animation this way:

   rabit.animate("die", false);

I need to wait after step 1. before making step 2. so that animation plays. How can I do that?

Comment: You may not need a script for this. Can you show your animator and the parameters ? I think you can use a trigger parameter instead of a boolean, and use auto-transition from your "die" state to your other state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AnimationEvent. It will besically give you an opportunity to call a function in the end of your animation.
More on that here [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can call a coroutine:

In C#:

```
IEnumerator PlayWaitPlay(){
      rabit.animate("die", true);
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(3); // your animation time
      rabit.animate("die", false);
}
```

To call it use

```
StartCoroutine(PlayWaitPlay());
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: How can I get the time of my animation from animator?

Comment: And your solution does not work.